# Is there a way to constrain a sum of Integers in a set to (0,1) without finding the maximum integer in the set?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, discrete-mathematics

I have a set of `n`, numbers `{N_1, N_2.....N_n}`

Basically I want to do something to the sum of all `N_k` that keeps the result of the sum normalized/bounded between `(0,1)` ( (like divide by some `f(N_1,N_2..N_n))` but I don't want to compare all integers in the set to find the maximum and I want to keep the answer "dimensionless" so `f` cannot be the sum of `(N_k)^2` for example.

Is there a simple function `f` or another way to ensure this?

**EDIT**
I want a mapping of all possible sums from `(0,infinity)` to `(0,1)`

`f = sum` will not work because it will always give a result of 1 and so is not proportional to the sum.

Assuming each term were a length in meters...dimensionless means that the end result of the operation should not have any units..e.g 2m + 3m/ (2m + 1m) =5/3 with no units.

However...there  fairly obvious answers that may work e.g. `f = sum +1 or f= sum +2` etc. These will grow with the sum and tend to 1 for large values of the sum
 the question is then perhaps more subjective and becomes which other kind of f can be used and which will give the "most linear" type of mapping for large values?

Comment: Well, the obvious would be for `f()` to simply compute the sum. Other than that, just about any function that is guaranteed to return an answer ≥ the sum satisfies your problem statement. You need to be more specific. To normalise data sets, the normalisation function is usually defined with reference to some known characteristic of the inputs (e.g., "N_i ≤ 1 for all i."), not the exact inputs themselves.

Comment: What's "dimensionless" supposed to mean? After all, `f` depends on your set elements, so `f=sum` seems to be a good choice.

Comment: marcelo and phillip see edits...hope these clarify...

Comment: @Philip: dimensionless means that `f` must scale linearly when the `x_n` are scaled by the same amount, so that the ratio sum / f does not change by a change of units. So `f` must be homogeneous of degree one. There are plenty of `f` available.

Answer (score 4):

atan(x/k)/(pi/2) maps all [0..infinity] to the range 0..1: [fooplot](http://fooplot.com/atan%28x/2%29/%28pi/2%29)

Pick a number k at least half as large as the largest number you expect to see. input k is mapped to 0.5.  Too large of inputs will be so close to each other and 1 as to be lost in the roundoff.

Comment: Thanks for the response!...yes i am trying to constrain the outputs but I want a map that is as linear as one can get...preferably something more linear than the inverse tangent?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: Pick a large enough k to make the region of interest roughly linear.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder you want a linear mapping... from 0 to infinity... to 0 to 1? How about just returning 0 all the time, since all finite numbers will be so close to zero as to be indistinguishable?

Answer (score 4):

> but I want a map that is as linear as one can get...preferably something more linear than the inverse tangent?

I'm not a mathematician, but my intuition is that the only way that you map from `(0, infinity)` to `(0, 1)` is with a function f that that has the property that f(x) is asymptotic to 1 as x tends to infinity.  It cannot be linear.

---

Per @Alexandre's comment, a revised statement should be:

- a function f that that has the property that f(x) is either constant or asymptotic to a constant as x tends to infinity.
- this means that it cannot be linear across the entire range ... except for the case of f(x) = C.

But like I said ... I'm not a mathematician ... and he apparently is.

Comment: It certainly won't be linear but we can try to find a function whose slope only changes for very large values...looks like I'd just have to fudge something with this property...thought this might be a standard problem.

Comment: or f is constant. If it is not, there is a direction in which it goes to infinity.

Comment: "looks like I'd just have to fudge" ... for instance if you set a realistic upper bound on the range of values, you could use a linear function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something dimensionless you **must** take `f` [**positive homogeneous**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) (by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) of dimensionless). This means that for each a > 0,

```
f(a * x_1, ..., a * x_n) = a * f(x_1, ..., x_n).
```

This ensures that

```
sum(a * x_1, ... a * x_n) / f(a * x_1, ..., a * x_n)
```

does not depend on `a` (see the multiplication by `a` as a "change of units"). Put another way, the function `f` must grow linearly when you scale evenly its arguments.

Basic examples of homogeneous functions are the ones you mentioned:

```
f(x_1, ..., x_n) = n * max(x_1, ..., x_n)                                     (1)
f(x_1, ..., x_n) = sum(x_1, ..., x_n)                                         (2)
```

but also the **Euclidean norm**:

```
f(x_1, ..., x_n) = sqrt(n) * sqrt(sum(x_1^2, ..., x_n^2))                     (3)
```

and the [***p*-norms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), for `p > 1`:

```
f(x_1, ..., x_n) = n^(p/(p-1)) * sum(x_1^p, ..., x_n^p) ^ (1/p)               (4)
```

As a bonus, they are symmetric, which may also be one of your requirements. Pick whichever you want. There are others, but are more complicated.

By [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) the ratio `sum / f` is always between zero and one for those four functions (this is why I chose the funny normalizing constants). Note that chosing `(2)` is a trivial choice: the result is always 1.

Comment: Wow ... there's a mathematician in the room!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a plain hyperbolic curve? The function *y=n/(x+n)* maps any positive number to the range [1,0]. The higher you choose n the flatter your curve becomes. If you take *y=1-n/(x+n)*, it will be in the range [0,1]. So the choice of n will indicate how fast your curve will near its assymptote.

Try here:
http://graph-plotter.cours-de-math.eu/

Comment: this does not yield dimensionless results.

Comment: In that case I think what you ask for is not possible. If you don't want to find and max number or sum of numbers, the best you can do is an heuristic. In my solution, if you choose *n* very very large, the curve will be nearing a line from [0,0] to [inf, 1]. Otherwise you need some way of knowing the upper bounds of your numbers.

Comment: see my answer for a renormalization which keeps the result scaling invariant and between 0 and 1.

Comment: I understood you the first time, and again, choose n as very very high, you'll get *almost* what you ask for. Cause I think that exactly what you ask for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can understand the question right. If you try to find a mapping that maps every individual element N<sub>1</sub>...N<sub>n</sub> to (0,1) you could certainly use (as you propose)

f(x) = x / max { N<sub>1</sub>, ..., N<sub>n</sub> }

but for some reason you don't want to take the maximum of all the elements. You can use

f(x) = x / ∑<sub>i</sub> N<sub>i</sub>

but this doesn't necessarily map any of the elements even near to 1. Another alternative is to use the "soft max" function, i.e.

f(x) = e<sup>x</sup> / [e<sup>N<sub>1</sub></sup> + ... + e<sup>N<sub>n</sub></sup>]

If the value of x is not necessarily any individual element of the set but a subset sum, then obviously

f(x) = x / ∑<sub>i</sub> N<sub>i</sub>

works very well, us now when x is the sum of all the elements you get to 1.

But then you say that x can tend to infinity. Can that really happen if the set { N<sub>i</sub> } is finite and remains constant?

In general if you want to compress from (0,∞) to (0,1) you can't do that with a linear function for obvious reasons. For a compression function f : (0,∞) → (0,1) you want d/dx f > 0 and necessarily lim x→∞ d/dx f(x) = 0; f(0) = 0; lim x→∞ f(x) = 1. Some functions with these properties are

1 - e<sup>-Cx</sup> for a any positive constant C, and

2 / (1 + e<sup>-Cx</sup>) - 1 (the Sigmoid function).

Comment: The functions you show are not homogeneous, and hence do not yield dimensionless results. Also, the OP wants the *renormalized sum* to be less than one.